# ByteBuddy: How to do method delegation / forwarding to a volatile field

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I have (pseudo code) something like this:

```
final Class<OUT> newClass = (Class<OUT>) new ByteBuddy()
.subclass(Object.class)
.name(newName)
.implement(SomeInterface.class, SomeOtherInterface.class)
.method(ElementMatchers.isMethod())                            
.intercept(
    ExceptionMethod.throwing(UnsupportedOperationException.class,
                            "calling this method is not supported"))
// in fact I am matching for more than a single method here
.method(ElementMatchers.named("getUuid"))
.intercept(
    MethodDelegation.toInstanceField(SomeOtherInterface.class, "delegate"))
.make()
.load(aBusinessEntityClass.getClassLoader(), ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.WRAPPER)
.getLoaded();
```

My current problem is: I need my *delegate* field to be *volatile*. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Your suggested solution is the easiest, unfortunately. I will try to make the API a bit more flexible in a future version: https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/issues/202

Comment: @RafaelWinterhalter: Thanks for your comment and adding a request for enhancement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, found a solution that works for me, in case anyone is interested:

```
final Class<OUT> newClass = (Class<OUT>) new ByteBuddy()
.subclass(Object.class)
.name(newName)
.implement(SomeInterface.class, SomeOtherInterface.class)
.method(ElementMatchers.isMethod())                            
.intercept(
    ExceptionMethod.throwing(UnsupportedOperationException.class,
                        "calling this method is not supported"))
// in fact I am matching for more than a single method here
.method(ElementMatchers.named("getUuid"))
.intercept(
    MethodDelegation.toInstanceField(SomeOtherInterface.class, "delegate"))
// -- HERE THE FIELD IS MODIFIED AGAIN, IN THIS CASE AS  --
// -- PRIVATE & VOLATILE                                 --
.field(ElementMatchers.named("delegate"))                       
.transform(Transformer.ForField.withModifiers(FieldManifestation.VOLATILE, Visibility.PRIVATE))
.make()
.load(aBusinessEntityClass.getClassLoader(), ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.WRAPPER)
.getLoaded();
```

The solution was to modify the field afterwards with a call to *field()* with *transform()* and appropriate *Transformer.ForField.withModifiers()*.

Hope to help everyone facing this issue.

Answer (score 4):

The `toInstanceField` API was retired with Byte Buddy 1.5.0 in favor of a new instrumentation API where you rather define the field explicitly:

```
new ByteBuddy()
  .defineField("delegate", SomeOtherInterface.class, VOLATILE)
  .method(ElementMatchers.named("getUuid"))
  .intercept(MethodDelegation.toField("delegate"));
```

This allows to do other things such as adding annotations etc.

This approach is now implemented for all `Implementation`s. The new version was released today.

Comment: Oh, that's a nice solution for my problem. In future projects I will possibly consider it! :-)